# Load testing on asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, performance-testing

I am setting up a load testing against asp.net mvc 4 application running on .Net Framework 4.5.

For Load testing we are using webperformance load tester 5.3. - http://www.webperformance.com/download/release/

The problem we are facing is the application hangs after 150 users, i mean while the load test is running and try to load the web it takes long time in minutes.

The load test we run is basic recorded as login in the application and on the dashboard link on few link that loads content - grid data with ajax.

The application in hosted on windows azure cloud service with 1 medium instance (2 core and 3.5GB Ram).

Any advise or suggestion will be appreciated.

Kind Regards
Bhavesh

Answer (score 2):

You can testing the application using Visual Studio 
Using Visual Studio 2013, you can create, manage, and run web performance tests and load tests.
To load test your app with on-premises resources or using cloud-based load testing, you first create web performance tests. These tests are used in your load tests to simulate multiple users performing actions in your app at the same time.

You can use cloud-based load testing service which allows you to run your tests across multiple virtual machines in the cloud. You can also use an on-premises test controllers and test agents. 
In the full version of Visual Studio Ultimate, the number of virtual users is unlimited. However, if you need to emulate thousands of users, use test controller and test agent machines. In Visual Studio Ultimate Trial version, the virtual user count is limited to 250.

For more information please visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn250793.aspx

Comment: If your application is public you can use the Cloud based Load testing solution with which you get 20,000 VUmins free per month. Details : https://www.visualstudio.com/features/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs